# Django encoding/decoding issues

Tags: python, django, encoding, special-characters, tastypie

so i am using a Django tastypie resource and i am trying to find a generic way to decode any string that may be posted to the resource.

i have for example a Name like this

> luiçscoico2#@!&&á

and i want my to be able to identify the type of encoding, and appropriately decode it.

I am trying to fetch the string like this:

> print bundle.data.get('first_name')

when i do a json dumps my string first name becomes like

> "lui\u00e7scoico2#@!&&\u00e1"

and i get an INTERNAL SERVER ERROR... any ideas?

UPDATE:
i do get a

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in
>   position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

if i try to decode('utf-8') before doing the json dumps to send to the server

Comment: set DEBUG = True in localsettings.py / settings.py to get the real error
next step would be to specify the encoding of the external resource, and use only unicode in django immediatelly after you dealt with the external encoding
to auto detect the encoding that is an interesting issue...

Comment: how do i specify the encoding in my external resource?

Comment: If you don't print anything the server returns an Internal Server Error as well?

Comment: no, only when i print or try to use the variables

Comment: Try to cover more code in your question, if the string get printed to the console (this is what I infer when you say "json dumps my string") the error is not raising there.

Comment: i can print the string with the json dump in the client only (no errors), but on the server side whenever i try to print or use the received strings i get the internal server error.. i can add more code but i am not sure it has more helpfull information

Comment: I see, well, I can tell that the string is encoded in unicode, it'll be useful to know what error is the server throwing exactly. Normally, if in DEBUG mode, Django dumps info of the exception to the browser screen, aren't you seeing that?

Comment: you are right, but in this case i im using celerybeat periodic tasks (not the browser), and the only error i get is an http error on the console...

Comment: i do get a UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128) if i try to decode('utf-8') before doing the json dumps to send to the server

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31114/discussion-between-paulo-bu-and-psychok7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'm gonna try to give a semi-blind answer here. Your string is already in `Unicode`, the reason I know this is because of the [u'\xe7' which is exactly the `ç` character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e7/index.htm).

This means you don't have to `encode` it. If you need your string in utf-8 then just do:

```
x.decode('utf-8')
```

and it will **porbably** work :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: my problem had nothing to do with encoding after all.. it was a server side error, but thanks for your time ;). ill still mark your answer as the correct one because it looks write to me

Comment: Thanks :) when I saw your last error yesterday a assumed it had nothing to do with encoding for instance but ok, I'm glad you managed to solve it :)

Comment: @psychok7 what was the server-side error?